# How can I make the following String arrays equal?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String[] tab1 = new String[]{"abc"}
String[] tab2 = new String[]{new String("abc")}

if(tab1 == tab2){

    ...
}
```

How can I make the if statement true so that I can perform the instructions?

Comment: To compare strings, use str1.equals(str2). Note that you don't have strings - so figure out how to get the string out of the array first.

Comment: DId you want to know how to compare two arrays of strings?  Or did you want to know how you can make the exact expression `tab1 == tab2` evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.equals(tab1, tab2);
```

**Explanation**

> The java.util.Arrays.equals(Object[ ] a, Object[ ] a2) method returns true if the two specified arrays of objects are equal to one another.The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal.Two objects e1 and e2 are considered equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).The two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.Two array references are considered equal if both are null.

Declaration for the method is
`public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)`

And since strings are objects in java, you can use this method to compare the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Two `new` objects are never equal; therefore, you cannot make two new arrays equal, because, you are explicitly creating a `new` array objects in both definitions.

Every time you use a `new` keyword, a *new* instance of the type [is being instantiated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9).

It's another story if you want to compare the elements of those two arrays, and for this, you first have to fetch the elements in question, and then compare, which in your case, would look like:

```java
if(tab1[0].equals(tab2[0])) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use some [Java API methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-arrays-java/) for array comparison.